# How do I remove the arrow inside a text input in Google Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

[image: Example text input with arrow]
How do I remove the arrow on the right from showing up during hover    and focus events in Google Chrome?

```
 input[type="text"]:focus{
      -moz-appearance: textfield;
    }
```

has worked for Firefox. I can't seem to find a working solution for Chrome.

```
    input[type="text"]:focus{
      -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
```

has not worked in Chrome 81.0.4044.129

Here's the relevant html portion (test.html):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="search-by-player-container">
            <input type="text" list="player-list-input" id="player-input-name" name="player-choice" />
            <datalist id="player-list-input"></datalist>
          </div>
          <script src="Scripts/loadPlayerNames.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here's the relevant css code (test.css):

```
    input[type="text"]:focus{
        -moz-appearance: textfield;
        margin:0;
      }

      input[type="text"]:focus{
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin:0;
      }
```

Here's the relevant js file (Scripts/loadPlayerNames.js):

```
    var input = document.getElementById("player-input-name");
    var dataList = document.getElementById("player-list-input");
    // Create a new XMLHttpRequest.
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Handle state changes for the request.
    request.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
      if (request.readyState === 4) {
        if (request.status === 200) {
          // Parse the JSON
          var jsonOptions = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

          // Loop over the JSON array.
          jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {
            // Create a new <option> element.
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            // Set the value using the item in the JSON array.
            option.value = item.name;
            // Add the <option> element to the <datalist>.
            dataList.appendChild(option);
          });

          // Update the placeholder text.
          input.placeholder = "player first & last name";

        } else {
          // An error occured :(
          input.placeholder = "Couldn't load datalist options :(";
        }
      }
    };

    // Update the placeholder text.
    input.placeholder = "Loading options...";

    // Set up and make the request.
    request.open('GET', '../Scraping/player_list.json', true);
    request.send();

    // START THE page with the focus on the player-input-name
    document.getElementById("player-input-name").focus();
```

Here's a portion of Scraping/player_list.json:

```
  [
  {
    "name": "Isaako Aaitui",
    "url": "/A/AaitIs00.htm",
    "position": "NT",
    "hall of fame": false,
    "first year": 2013,
    "last year": 2014,
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe Abbey",
    "url": "/A/AbbeJo20.htm",
    "position": "E",
    "hall of fame": false,
    "first year": 1948,
    "last year": 1949,
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Fay Abbott",
    "url": "/A/AbboFa20.htm",
    "position": "BB-FB-TB-QB-WB-E",
    "hall of fame": false,
    "first year": 1921,
    "last year": 1929,
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Tony Zuzzio",
    "url": "/Z/ZuzzTo20.htm",
    "position": "G",
    "hall of fame": false,
    "first year": 1942,
    "last year": 1942,
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Brandon Zylstra",
    "url": "/Z/ZylsBr00.htm",
    "position": "WR",
    "hall of fame": false,
    "first year": 2018,
    "last year": 2019,
    "active": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Jim Zyntell",
    "url": "/Z/ZyntJi20.htm",
    "position": "G",
    "hall of fame": false,
    "first year": 1933,
    "last year": 1935,
    "active": false
  }
]
```

Comment: -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't worked. Maybe I have a bug somewhere else.

Comment: Edit your question and put html code also. I will check

Comment: Hi Nitin, that's really helpful and kind of you. I'll edit the question to include more code.